# Is there a verb that means "to make someone feel special"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb that means "to make someone feel special"? I've used that same phrase one too many times in the same piece and would love to mix it up!

For example: "On your child's birthday every year, harness the power of family traditions to *make your child feel special*."

You could use something like "...harness the power of family traditions *to delight your child*" but that doesn't bring the same meaning.

From my perspective, to make someone feel special isn't just about making them happy or excited -- it's about making them feel that *they* matter to you and that you appreciate them for who they are.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: There are expressions like "spend quality time with someone" or "boost someone's self-esteem", but they're not single-word verbs.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***celebrate***? It works doubly with the birthday aspect.

> **1.** To observe (a day or event) with ceremonies of respect, festivity, or rejoicing. See Synonyms at observe.
>
> **3.** To extol or praise: *a sonnet that celebrates love.*
>
> <sub>Source: [The Free Dictionary at *American
> Heritage*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/celebrate)</sub>

So:

> *Harness the power of family traditions to celebrate your child on her special day.*

Answer (score 0):

Informally, one can use the multi-word verb **big up [for]**:

> *big up (to/for) somebody* [spoken; informal]
>
> used when you want to praise someone
>
> - *Big up to Kelly Holmes! She ran a superb race.*

[[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/big-up-to-for-somebody)] [adjusted]

Although Collins still considers *big up* a slang usage, the [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/big+up) gives the transitive usage without adding even an 'informal' caveat:

> *big up*
>
> 1. To promote or aggrandize the importance, quality, or positive aspects of someone or something.
>
> - *The promoters have really been bigging up this new band* ....

Answer (score 0):

***Uplift*** is good here.  It carries the idea of the inherent worth of the person.

"...harness the power of family traditions to ***uplift*** your child"

> To elevate in rank, honour, estate, or estimation. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/219993?rskey=g1c0OH&result=1#eid)

Also according to OED, in Scottish it has the particular meaning of *make proud* as well.   This fits with the OP's request for a word that doesn't just indicate a feeling of happiness but a feeling that they matter and have value.

Answer (score 0):

I think one might loosely use "inspire" here.

> to stimulate to greater or higher activity : make spirited
>
> Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspire#kidsdictionary)

It's not an exact match for "make someone feel special", but I think it captures "make someone feel {positive}".

> "On your child's birthday every year, harness the power of family traditions to inspire your child."